# CouchBase map multiple documents with key prefix

Tags: couchbase, data-retrieval

I have the following keys in my Couch DB :

```
content_HASHKEY
content_info_HASHKEY
```

In the above example the HASHKEY is unique in both my documents however the prefix and document content vary for both and for my web client I do not want them to be making multiple Couch DB calls to retrieve both pieces of information (related ot the same HASHKEY), what is the most efficient way to retrieve both the documents in a single call from Couch base Db ?

EDIT :
DO I actually need the HASHKEY to be a property insideexach of the documents as well to be able to JOIN them ?:

```
content_HASHKEY
     HashKeyVal : HASHKEY
content_info_HASHKEY
     HashKeyVal : HASHKEY
```

Comment: When you say the hashkey is "unique" in the two document types, do you mean it's the same in both, or actually unique, as in different between the two prefixes? Also, which SDK are you using for this?

Comment: Actually I meant those are same across those documents. Im using CB 2.5.1